# isEnabled() function always returns true in case drop-down option is disabled

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In a drop-down list the 'Delete' option is disabled. While I am trying to check the option if it is enabled or disabled, by using isEnabled() function. The below code always returns true, which is incorrect. What should I do?

```
if(Delete.isEnabled())
{
    System.out.print("\Button is enabled. Take your action.");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("\Button is disabled. Take your action.");
}
    
//Assert.assertTrue(Delete.isEnabled());
//Delete.isEnabled();
```

Or

```
System.out.println(Delete.isEnabled());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b2TV.png)

Comment: Can you share a link to that page or at least HTML of block of elements containing that element both in disabled and enabled state?

Comment: I have added screenshot

Comment: This screenshot is absolutely useless. We need to see the HTML. In both states.